# Best way to store and version lookup Entities in local storage

Tags: breeze

For my SPA I have a series of Lookup entities that are loading into my entity manager on page load for various pick lists and lookup values.  What I'd like to do is store these entities in local storage and import them into my manager instead of requesting them over the network.

These lookups can be edited by 3 people in my company.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to version these lookups in local storage so that the file can be updated when a lookup changes (or at least give the client-side capability for determining when the records stale to request new ones).  How can I achieve this? My lookups are simply tables in my overall database, and I don't see a way for the client-side to recognize when the lookups have changed.

I'm reluctant to add a timestamp column because I would need to evaluate the entities in local storage and compare them to the ones on the database and get the ones needed.  Not sure how I would save page load time there.

I'm considering moving all of my lookups into a separate database and version the whole thing, requesting new lookups when any one of them changes.  I would need to write a mechanism for versioning this db whenever one of the 3 people makes an edit.

Has anyone found a better solution to a problem of this type?  My lookups() function is cannibalizing the wait time on users' first access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider maintaining a separate version file or web API endpoint.

Invalidate lookups by type or as a whole rather than individually.

Bump the version number(s) when anything changes. Stash version number with your local copy. Compare and reload as needed.